# Windows Hyper-V ran out of memory

Tags: linux, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows 2016 Hyper-V machine that holds a Linux VM.   The link VM is running at 12GB RAM and I want to increase that. When I try to increase it is says it ran out of memory.

1. There is 12 GB Free on server
2. All windows updates are installed
3. I can create another VM with 6 GB of RAM and it starts up fine; I just can't add it to this VM.  I can't even add 2 GB to the VM in question.
4. Numa is off.
5. Guest Services is installed.

Any suggestions?  I have read countless forums but can not resolve the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to enable Numa Spanning in Hyper-V settings.

Comment: I have Numa disabled in the Linux OS.  Does that matter?

Comment: He is referring to the Hyper-V host, not the guest.

Answer (score 6):

Check the NUMA spanning in Hyper-V settings. Looks like you tried to assign more RAM memory that you have on a single NUMA. By enabling this option you will be able to assign more memory to the VM! https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/a-closer-look-at-numa-spanning-and-virtual-numa-settings

Comment: Can I have the Hyper-V host have Numa spanning and the Linux Guest have it turned off and not run into any issues?

Comment: Sure. But why should you enable NUMA spanning and do not use it?